# Wrap text using CSS for a button to display code with javascript interaction

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, word-wrap

I'm trying to set a drop-down menu to display HTML code. Everything is working perfectly except that longer sections of code do not wrap or break onto the next line. The result is that the user can not see longer strands of code. I've inserted Lorem Ipsum as an example.

I have tried MANY inline styles on the **code** element and the containing **div** element. This **div** contains other styling for the text (such as color) with no problem.

I've tried width, overflow, word-break, and a number of other things. I'm out of ideas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .accordion {
            background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
            color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 18px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            transition: 0.4s;
            width: 400px;
            font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size:larger;
        }

        .active, .accordion:hover {
            background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
        }

        .panel {
            padding: 0 18px;
            background-color: white;
            display: none;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        nav {
            background-color: gray;
            padding: 18px;
            margin: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }

        a {
            padding: 3%;
            color: white;
            font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
            font-size:larger;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="index.html">Student 1</a>
        <a href="www.yahoo.com">Student 2</a>
        <a href="www.yahoo.com">Student 3</a>
        <a href="www.yahoo.com">Student 4</a>
        <a href="www.yahoo.com">Student 5</a>
    </nav>

    <button class="accordion">Click here to see the code I wrote!</button>
        <div class="panel" style="color: limegreen; background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);">
            <figure>
                <pre>
                    <code>
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora reprehenderit quod dolore totam a alias quibusdam, consectetur rerum saepe, doloribus asperiores quo nam aut est mollitia quia non similique quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor vel ipsam esse reprehenderit laborum? Corrupti, labore inventore laudantium officiis eveniet commodi porro ullam hic obcaecati asperiores suscipit, saepe quia eaque.
                    </code>
                </pre>
            </figure>
        </div>
    
    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;
    
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
    
    
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        
            if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                panel.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                panel.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not bad for a first post!  :)  You'll find that Stack Overflow has a snippet editor in the question editor where you can put the HTML and JavaScript code in and it will be runnable (similar to sites like jsfiddle or codepen).  Try editing your question and putting the code into a snippet.  It's the icon in the toolbar between _Image_ and _Numbered List_.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I got the snippet running!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried different values for `white-space` on the code and parent pre element? Seems to fix it right up for me.

Comment: Thank you! I found that for my purposes, this worked for preserving the tabs in the code:

    <code style="white-space: break-spaces;">

I will have to brush-up on how white-space works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple issues with the code tag that I fixed but also a few with various margins and padding that seemed to be off. Here's an update that should work. `

```
<style>
    .accordion {
        background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
        color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 14px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        transition: 0.4s;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size:small;
    }

    .active, .accordion:hover {
        background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    }

    .panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    nav {
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 14px 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        border: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    .pre{
        width: 100%;
    }

    code{
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: normal;
        max-width:80%; 
        word-break:break-all; 
        word-wrap:break-word;
    }

    a {
        padding: 3%;
        color: white;
        font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
        font-size:medium
    }

    body {
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

`